Can I utilize Seachem's pH Alert in saltwater?
Can I utilize Seachem's pH Alert in Saltwater? The package says freshwater only, however, I assume that this is because the "dangerous" segment on the indicator would be far higher for Saltwater.
However, wouldn't the mechanics be the same? Is there any reason not to utilize it in my aquarium?
